# How do you remove the background when using image as planes and importing a png?

Tags: modeling

This question may be very beginner but I am at a loss of things to do. I am using blender for 3d printing, I want to remove the background of this sword so only the outline is left. I think I should use the knife tool to cut the outline out just like some other apps like inkscape, have already done the knifed outline but do not know how to select it so that it deletes the outer part leaving only the sword. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do it in another software (Gimp for instance) before importing it to Blender.

But as it is, you can modify the shader created by *image as plane* like so:

[image]

As the colors are grey and white, it outputs 1 for white and 0 for grey.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do so with planes to images but you can use [Img 2 mesh](https://kjell.gumroad.com/l/i2m)